# Help in creating tables, errors in code

Tags: tables

I am beginner of LaTeX. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter as editor. I tried following code to create merged table but I got 101 errors! I want to create PDF file and not able to understand what went wrong. Probably, am I not using correct package? Please help, following is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabls}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\section{Table 1}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}

\multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{Input}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Output}\\

\head{Group A} & \head{Group B} & \head{Group C} \\

cmidrule[2pt](lr){1-2} \cmidrule[1pt](r){3}

30 & 50 & 80\\

10 & 20 & 30\\

1 & 5 & 6\\

\bottomrule[1.5pt]

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The editor is showing error at first `\multicolumn` line. It is showing

> pdflatex-> !undefined control sequence.

Comment: 1. The second `\multicolumn` is not needed. It does not affect the output. 2. In the actual log, directly following `! Undefined control sequence`, you can see that `\head` is the problem as it gets an own line.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what `\head` is, so I have defined it below as `\textbf`.

The only package required for the table below is [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs).

The `\cmidrule` macro requires a range of columns, so instead of `{3}` you need to specify `{3-3}`.  You were also missing a `\` prior to the first `\cmidrule`.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
%\usepackage{tabls} 
%\usepackage{ctable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
%\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand*{\head}[1]{\textbf{#1}}%

\begin{document} \section{Table 1}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}

\multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{Input}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Output}\\
\head{Group A} & \head{Group B} & \head{Group C} \\
\cmidrule[2pt](lr{0.75em}){1-2} \cmidrule[1pt](r){3-3}
30 & 50 & 80\\
10 & 20 & 30\\
 1 &  5 &  6\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For beginners, I believe it is useful to see the minimum code necessary to accomplish the spirit of your task.  Take a look at this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|cc|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Input} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Output}\\
\hline
Group A & Group B & Group C \\
\hline
30 & 50 & 80\\
10 & 20 & 30\\
1 & 5 & 6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The other packages in your header expand the capabilities of LaTeX's `tabular` environment.  Add them as you reach `tabular`'s limitations (like multiple page tables).